# Java logical XOR("^") vs logical NOT("!")

Tags: java, javafx, bit-manipulation

Through looking some custom libraries in JavaFX https://github.com/HanSolo/submitbutton/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/hansolo/submitbutton/Demo.java.

> I came along with this piece of code:

```
                 if (toggle) {  //where toogle is a boolean
                    if (progress > 0.75) {
                            progress = 0;
                            button.setFailed();
                            timer.stop();
                            toggle ^= true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (progress > 1) {
                            progress = 0;
                            timer.stop();
                            toggle ^= true;
                        }
                    }
                 }
```

> Question

Why the coder wrote  `toggle ^= true;` which i understand what it does [following the table below](http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-bitwise-xor-operator/):

```
A   B   A ^ B
0   0     0
0   1     1
1   0     1
1   1     0
```

instead using `toggle=!toggle;`?

Is that a pattern,it has to do with any performance improvement or it is personal preference?I am curious though cause first time i see this...

Comment: IMHO that just looks like unnecessary obfuscation. You should use `!` when you mean to negate a boolean.

Comment: Looks like somebody just bragging about their knowledge of bit-wise operators (unnecessary in this case if you ask me). My 2 cents.

Comment: `someReallyLongVariableName ^= true;` might be easier to read than `someReallyLongVariableName = !someReallyLongVariableName;`.

Comment: I'm more curious why it's using a toggle altogether, when they can be explicitly set to true or false.

Comment: @shmosel Indeed, since it's wrapped in that `if(..)`, it's equivalent to `toggle = false ;`. I think I probably wouldn't trust a library that had code like that in it.

Comment: @James_D Except of that it is a really nice looking custom item.http://harmoniccode.blogspot.gr/2016/09/friday-fun-xxxviii.html

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, it is not a "bitwise operation" between booleans.  It's a "logical operation".   The operators between booleans and the operators between ints are different, though are related.

Comment: `True=1` and `False=0`  and then it works like on numbers or i am wrong?What you mean?

Comment: @GoXR3Plus The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2) calls them 'boolean logical operators' when the operands are boolean.

Comment: @GoXR3Plus It's really just terminology, but in Java (unlike C) `false` is completely distinct from `0`; they are different types and not interchangeable. It is not correct to say "`true=1` and `false=0`". So the *bitwise* `^` operator is an operator that works on numeric types; it is distinct from the *boolean logical operator* `^` that operates on booleans; they are two completely different operators, even though they use the same syntax. The point being made is that the title of your question is wrong.

Comment: @James_D How it works behind the scene this operator for booleans then?If you want add an answer about that so i can accept one.